# Different Spark Input and Output formats

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce

What are different input and output formats supported out of the box in Spark?

Map Reduce supports quite a few of them, but I am seeing only textFile and objectFile in Spark.

Also how can I leverage Hadoop input/output formats in Spark?

Comment: what do you mean by i/p & output formats?? You can read from & wirte to **hdfs, filesystem, database** with spark

Comment: Are you familiar with Hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save RDDs as any traditional Hadoop file format by calling `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile` on most RDD types, e.g. the [PairRDDFunctions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions), and read them by calling `newAPIHadoopFile` on the [SparkContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Java? Check out all the `saveAs` functions on RDDs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaHadoopRDD), and all the input functions in `JavaSparkContext` class [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext).